# Encryption function assignment in C

Tags: c, debugging, encryption

I have an assignment for the university to create a function that encrypts in C language. The full information is given below:

> A scheme to encrypt letters is to fill a 8 x 8 array with the 26
> capital letters of the English alphabet, the 26 small letters of the
> English, the ten digits ’0 ’ through ’9 ’, the space character ‘ ‘
> and the ‘.’ character. Each character appears exactly once in the
> array. This array is called the encryption key.
>
> To encrypt a letter pair, the rectangle formed by the two letters is
> used. Each letter of the original pair is replaced by the letter
> located on the same row and in the other corner of the rectangle. If
> both letters happen to be in the same row or column, the letters are
> swapped.
>
> For example, according to the following key, the pair of letters  AQ
> is encrypted as GV. Note the rectangle formed by the letters A and Q,
>
> The letter A is replaced by G, which is the letter located on the
> same row and in the other corner of the rectangle.
>
> The letter Q is replaced by V, which is the letter located on the same
> row and in the other corner of the rectangle.
>
> Define and implement a function named encrypt  that takes 3 arguments:
>
> A 2-D array of characters as the encryption key,
>
> The message to be encrypted (as a null-terminated array of
> characters)
>
> An array of characters can be used to store the encrypted message.
>
> The function encrypts the message according to the scheme described
> above and stores the encrypted message in the third parameter. If the
> original message contains an odd number of letters the last letter is
> unchanged.
>
> Note: The terminating null should NOT be encrypted
>
> For example, the word COMPUTER will be encrypted as VcrqGc
>
> Note: for simplicity: The function named generate_key is already
> provided with this assignment. You do not have to create it. The
> function randomly fills an 8 x 8 array with the 26 capital letters of
> the English alphabet, the 26 small letters of the ten digits ’0 ’
> through ’9 ’, the space ‘ ‘ and the dot    ‘ .’.

I have created this function but it returns -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

```
void encrypt(char key[][8],char word[], char done[]){

    int x,y,t,w,z,c=0;

    while(word[c] != '\0'){

        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){

         for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            

            if(word[c]==key[i][j]){
                x=i;
                y=j;
                }
            if(word[c+1]==key[i][j]){
                    w=i;
                    z=j;
                    }

            t=x;
            x=w;
            w=t;
            done[c]=key[x][y];
            done[c+1]=key[w][z];


            }
                     printf("\n");


        }
        c=c+2;
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can the function return anything if it is declared as `void`?

Comment: Did you mean segfault? Error `C0000005` (-1073741819) is an access violation, typically caused by a buffer overrun.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the code that calls the function.  Are you declaring enough space for the `done` array?

Comment: The indexing variables `x, y, w, z` are not initialised under all circumstances. Uninitialised local variables do not have a default value, they are indeterminate.

Comment: Why are you assigning to your `done` array inside the inner search loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how you are calling this function, I built some supporting code to call this function.  What I determined was that instead of testing the first and second character in a character pair in series like you have your code, you need to perform another loop test on the second character nested inside when the coordinates are found for the first character.  Following is a bit of refactored code illustrating the nesting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char key[8][8] = {  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'},
                    {'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'},
                    {'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X'},
                    {'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'},
                    {'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'},
                    {'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v'},
                    {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3'},
                    {'4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' ', '.'},
};

void encrypt(char key[][8],char word[], char done[])
{

    int x = 0, y = 0, t = 0, w = 0, z = 0, c=0;

    while(word[c] != 0)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
            {
                if(word[c]==key[i][j])
                    if(word[c + 1] == 0)            /* Odd number of letters - switch and exit here */
                    {
                        done[c] = key[j][i];
                        done[c + 1] = 0;            /* Tidy up */
                        return;
                    }
                {
                    printf("i: %d, j: %d ", i, j);  /* Nest the check of the second letter inside the first letter check */
                    for (int m = 0; m < 8; m++)
                    {
                        for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++)
                        {
                            if(word[c+1]==key[m][n])
                            {
                                printf("m: %d, n: %d \n", m, n);
                                w=m;  /* Corrected per comments */
                                z=j;
                                x=i;
                                y=n;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                done[c]=key[x][y];
                done[c+1]=key[w][z];
                if ((x == w) || (y == z))  /* Special case where either the letters are in the same row or same column */
                {
                    done[c + 1]=key[x][y];
                    done[c]=key[w][z];
                }
            }
        }
        c=c+2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char test_word[32];
    char encrypted_word[32];

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        encrypted_word[i] = 0;
    }

    strcpy(test_word, "Products");

    encrypt(key, test_word, encrypted_word);

    printf("Word: %s, Encrypted Word: %s\n", test_word, encrypted_word);

    strcpy(test_word, encrypted_word);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        encrypted_word[i] = 0;
    }

    encrypt(key, test_word, encrypted_word);

    printf("Word: %s, Encrypted Word: %s\n", test_word, encrypted_word);

    return 0;
}
```

Since theoretically, placing the encrypted word through this function should decrypt the word, I just called the function twice using a specific literal word to test.  Following was the output on my terminal proving out this theory.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Encryption/bin/Release$ ./Encryption 
i: 1, j: 7 m: 5, n: 3 
i: 5, j: 0 m: 3, n: 5 
i: 5, j: 6 m: 3, n: 4 
i: 5, j: 5 m: 5, n: 4 
Word: Products, Encrypted Word: d5rFj1lt
i: 3, j: 5 m: 7, n: 1 
i: 5, j: 3 m: 0, n: 5 
i: 4, j: 3 m: 6, n: 5 
i: 4, j: 5 m: 5, n: 5 
Word: d5rFj1lt, Encrypted Word: Products
```

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  FYI, if you want to make this function more robust so that it could handle words with an odd number of letters, immediately inside the test block for the second letter and immediately before launching the inner for loop, you might want to add a test like "if(word[c + 1] == 0) { done[c] = key[j][i]; done[c + 1] = 0; return; }" to exit gracefully when there are an odd number of letters.  Regards.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that the first two chars 'P' & 'r' do not encode to 'd' and '5'... Draw the rectangle over the matrix in your code. The 'opposite corners' for that letter pair are 'L' and 'v'... I've posted a shortened implementation...

Comment: You are correct sir.  My issue was the population of the four work indices.  In effect my original shuffle of the index variables was kind of rotating the rectangle and then populating index values.  When I revised the updates to "w=m; z=j; x=i; y=n; " my algorithm agrees with your program.  Good catch.

Comment: if the word I want to encrypt is odd how may I edit the code to keep the last letter as it is? because I tried to add this piece of code(                                    while(word[g]!=0){
        g++;}   
      if(g%2!=0)
        done[g-1]=word[g-1];                                                                                                                                                                                             
 ) after the while loop but it didn't work

Comment: I added in the block of code I used to handle if the word has an odd number of letters in the example above.  It is right before the last nested for loop.  It does a one-off encryption of the last letter.  I've tried it with odd-numbered letters.  Try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (correct) alternate solution that takes advantage of the modulo operator.

Contiguous bytes in memory can be viewed as "8x8" or "64x1"... The approach below invokes `strchr()` to find each input letter, then its index. The row & col can be derived from the byte's index. 'Pairing' the row of the 1st with the col of the 2nd involves some careful integer and modulo division.

The `while()` conditional will only do pairs, and a bit of extra code handles the final char for string lengths that are odd.

```
void encrypt( char key[], char word[], char done[] ) {
    for( int c = 0; word[c] != 0 && word[c+1] != 0 ; c += 2 ) {
        int loc0 = strchr( key, word[ c+0 ] ) - key;
        int loc1 = strchr( key, word[ c+1 ] ) - key;

        done[ c+0 ] = key[ ( loc0 / 8 ) * 8 + ( loc1 % 8 ) ];
        done[ c+1 ] = key[ ( loc1 / 8 ) * 8 + ( loc0 % 8 ) ];
    }
    if( word[c] != 0 ) { done[ c ] = word[ c ]; c += 1; }
    done[ c ] = '\0';

    printf( "'%s' ==> '%s'\n", word, done );
}

char key[] = "ABCDEFGH"
             "IJKLMNOP"
             "QRSTUVWX"
             "YZabcdef"
             "ghijklmn"
             "opqrstuv"
             "wxyz0123"
             "456789 .";

void main( void ) {
    char buf[2][32];

    encrypt( key, "Products", buf[0] );

    encrypt( key, buf[0], buf[1] );
}
```

This encryption corrects some mysterious 'transposition' so it does not match NoDakker's version. (But, this version of the output checks out manually using NoDakker's supplied 'matrix'.)

```
Output:
'Products' ==> 'LvtYsest'
'LvtYsest' ==> 'Products'
```